# Constructing a pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following data frame that I want to construct like it

```
  id,x,y,time
```

My input data is like that
 each frame:

```
point_lists = defaultdict(list)

id= id.astype(np.int32)

point_lists[id].append(center_pt.T)

    saved_x = [i[0] for i in point_lists[id]]
    saved_y = [i[1] for i in point_lists[id]]
    x = list(map(lambda dd: float(dd[0]),saved_x))
    y = list(map(lambda dd: float(dd[0]),saved_y))
```

Now I want panadas as

```
ID1,  List of it's X, List of it's Y, FrameIDX
ID2,  List of it's X, List of it's Y, FrameIDX
ID3,  List of it's X, List of it's Y, FrameIDX
```

The problem I can't concatent the List of X and List of Y into the dataframe.
I'm doing a video processing of centers ( x,y) and I don't have an idea of how to keep ID --> List of it's x, List of it's y and the frame idx at that time.

Sample of expected Panadas Dataframe

```
  ,trajectory_id,frame,x   ,y   ,t  ,s                  ,v                  ,side,is_primary,s_centered         ,s_normalized       ,is_crossing,is_long,is_close,is_valid
    0 ,1            ,1    ,-2.0,-2.0,0.0,0.0                ,                   ,1   ,True      ,-3.6587033144922905,0.0                ,True       ,True   ,True    ,True
    1 ,1            ,2    ,0.1 ,-1.5,1.0,2.1587033144922905 ,2.1587033144922905 ,1   ,True      ,-1.5               ,0.30304431375902774,True       ,True   ,True    ,True
    2 ,1            ,3    ,0.1 ,0.0 ,2.0,3.6587033144922905 ,1.5                ,1   ,True      ,0.0                ,0.5136181650089165 ,True       ,True   ,True    ,True
    3 ,1            ,4    ,0.1 ,1.5 ,3.0,5.158703314492291  ,1.5                ,-1  ,True      ,1.5000000000000004 ,0.7241920162588055 ,True       ,True   ,True    ,True
    4 ,1            ,5    ,2.0 ,2.0 ,4.0,7.123391584931141  ,1.96468827043885   ,-1  ,True      ,3.46468827043885   ,1.0                ,True       ,True   ,True    ,True
    5 ,2            ,2    ,-2.0,2.0 ,0.0,0.0                ,                   ,-1  ,False     ,-1.9646882704388506,0.0                ,True       ,True   ,True    ,True
    6 ,2            ,3    ,-0.1,1.5 ,1.0,1.9646882704388506 ,1.96468827043885   ,-1  ,False     ,0.0                ,0.27580798374119475,True       ,True   ,True    ,True
    7 ,2            ,4    ,-0.1,0.0 ,2.0,3.4646882704388506 ,1.5                ,1   ,False     ,1.5                ,0.4863818349910837 ,True       ,True   ,True    ,True
    8 ,2            ,5    ,-0.1,-1.5,3.0,4.964688270438849  ,1.5                ,1   ,False     ,2.9999999999999982 ,0.6969556862409724 ,True       ,True   ,True    ,True
    9 ,2            ,6    ,2.0 ,-2.0,4.0,7.123391584931138  ,2.1587033144922905 ,1   ,False     ,5.158703314492287  ,1.0                ,True
```

Comment: Hi - welcome to Stack Overflow - Can you add some more details please on things you have tried? What is the output you are getting right now and what do you expect?

Comment: I wrote what I expect, I don't know how to formulate pandas dataframe as shown in the post

Comment: Hi Waleed,  please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples.  You need to have properly formed and working python code for people to help out.  It is also super helpful if your provided code can embody the input data.

Comment: @RichAndrews I put a sample of expected dataframe

Comment: Hi Waleed, people who may be able to answer need a copy/paste-able working version of your code.  You are providing no input DataFrame, your code has and  indentation issue, etc.    See the accepted answer here for guidance: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples